# Best books on A Second Course in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, big-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prerequisites/Books for Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43930/prerequisites-books-for-linear-algebra)

I've studied from David Poole's *Linear Algebra: A Modern Introduction* However, it's not very complete. I want to study subjects as Bilinear Forms, Transformations. And also, I want to study it more deeply.

Do you know of any book on Linear Algebra that studies the subject deeply but also explains it clearly? I prefer the practical approach over the theoretic one.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prerequisites/Books for Linear Algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43930/prerequisites-books-for-linear-algebra) and [Where to start learning Linear Algebra?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/where-to-start-learning-linear-algebra)

Comment: I recommend Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel and Spence. Its an introduction to the subject and covers only the finite dimensional cases, but makes very little compromises in terms of depth. I'm not sure whether bilinear forms in particular are covered though.

Comment: @PZZ  I second this recommendation. Probably the most comprehensive text on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at [Chicago undergraduate mathematics bibliography](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm#i%3alinear-algebra).

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130084514) by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence.