# Short First Course in linear algebra text

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I am currently reading a bit of real analysis from Dr Pugh's book and I intend to study abstract algebra from Dummit and Foote in a short time.

However, I wish to explore linear algebra in the meantime and I was wondering if someone could recommend a short linear algebra text(100-150 pages) which covers important topics well  like Vector spaces, bases , dimensions,operations on matrices, eigenvalues and related topics which are necessary for multivariate analysis.I would appreciate a rigorous book aimed at pure mathematics students.

Thanks!

Comment: You can read two chapters from I.N. Herstein's Topics in Algebra; namely Vector Spaces and Linear Transformations.

Comment: Are you sure that the later chapters are logically independent of the previous ones?

Comment: Almost 95%. You can always look up an odd definition or two (such as what is the definition of field, what is an abelian group etc) from the previous chapters.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43930/prerequisites-books-for-linear-algebra, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/where-to-start-learning-linear-algebra, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89003/best-books-on-linear-algebra, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160056/what-is-a-good-book-to-study-linear-algebra

Answer (score 2):

If you already have some experience with linear algebra, I think Halmos' [Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387900934) fits the bill. It's actually around 200 pages, but if you were short on time you can cover the first 150 pages and still get *way* more than you need for multivariate analysis.