# Book recommendations for a better foundation in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

I'm taking linear algebra next semester, and through a few searches online, apparently it only really requires that you be pretty good/intuitive at analytic geometry and manipulating algebraic expressions.

For the latter, I'd say I'm pretty okay with that since I'm currently in Calc 2 which requires a lot of it, however, if you have any recommendations  that'll help me become faster/better at the craft--I'm all ears!!

However, my knowledge on analytic geometry is pretty...meager? Basically, I hear that vectors, matrices, and the like will be involved a lot and I have not touched these in my past calc classes, and barely did any of that in in high school (I took a curriculum that mixed all pre-calculus subjects together, and it did not emphasize vectors at all). I've NEVER taken a class that used complex numbers, either. I'm not looking to become an expert, but I do want to familiarize myself more with these concepts so it comes more intuitively when linear algebra gets more and more difficult throughout the semester.

For reference, here is the book I am going to be using for next sem:
[https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Applications-Steve-Leon/dp/0136009298/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136009298)

Also, I found a forum online that provides a good resource for free on google:
https://books.google.com/books?id=Yo0LAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA7&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

However, it is 600+ pages long and surely not all of that is important/necessary to become good at linear algebra.

Any recommendations/what important section is needed to succeed in linear algebra?

Thank you so much!

P.S. I'm taking this for my CS major, which i hear linear algebra is really really important in becoming a better programmer/problem solver.

Comment: There's a set of notes called "linear algebra done wrong", which is quite good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prerequisites/Books for A First Course in Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43930/prerequisites-books-for-a-first-course-in-linear-algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're a CS major, I recommend MOOC's [*Linear Algebra: Foundations to Frontiers*](https://www.coursetalk.com/providers/edx/courses/linear-algebra-foundations-to-frontiers-2?page=1&sort=-created_at#incourse-reviews) on edX.  It contains exercises, videos, and programming exercises which links mathematical abstractions to their programming counterparts.  It is free of charge, including a book of 800 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this book: http://www.bigwords.com/search/easy-search/?category_name=books&searchtype=author&searchEngineType=bettersearch&category_id=1000&searchstring=Fraleigh+Beauregard

I used the book by Steven Leon (which is more focused on application), but I enjoyed using this one more (which I think is better for studying the theory of linear algebra).