# list of linear algebra book

Tags: reference-request

I am complex geometer/algebraic geometry student. I realized I need to strengthen my linear algebra. It would be nice if someone could post a list of linear algebra books they use for research. In particular if there is connections to vector bundles as well, but something that is complete. I am not looking for a most complete book for the above, but list of references.

Comment: Hoffman & Kunze; Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Peter Lax; Friedberg, Insel, and Spence; Linear Algebra Done Right; Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Strang

Comment: _Linear Algebra_ by Greub

Comment: Loehr has a very comprehensive Advanced Linear Algebra text (https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Linear-Algebra-Textbooks-Mathematics/dp/1466559012).

Comment: @ml0105 Thank you Loehr is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: @littleO... Yeah... Kenneth Hoffman (MIT) and Ray Kunze can be an alternative for people who struggle with abstract ideas from the very beginning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prerequisites/Books for A First Course in Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43930/prerequisites-books-for-a-first-course-in-linear-algebra)