# Video Lectures for Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, online-resources

Are there any video lectures for linear algebra **other than Strang's?**. I'm looking for something more pure. Ideally, from a professor who follows a book similar to Hoffman and Kunze or Axler.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe your question is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/where-to-start-learning-linear-algebra)

Comment: Maybe I'm being really dumb but I couldn't find it there. I had already checked it. People suggested books but not video lectures.

Comment: There's a link to the MIT lectures on LA. But I see now that the instructor there is Strang.

Comment: me too want video lectures following something like Axler.

Answer (score 15):

I have made a new series of videos to accompany *Linear Algebra Done Right*. These videos are available here: http://www.linear.axler.net/LADRvideos.html

Answer (score 8):

This series of video lectures by Jason Morton from Penn State follows Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right (3rd edition):

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLflMyS1QOtxwiN5oOuyY4W_8fZlTTnRcF

Website accompany the lectures:

http://jasonmorton.github.io/LinearAlgebra/

Answer (score 7):

There is some material on vector spaces in the abstract algebra videos of Benedict Gross. The course text is Michael Artin's Algebra, as a guide to level.

http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JibVXBElKL0

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE0xIpf11Qo

you may like this one

Comment: The first one **is** by Gilbert Strang (see OP's question).

Comment: @J.D. oh i didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

illinios lecture purely based on axler book
https://felixleditzky.info/teaching/FT21/MATH416_linear_algebra.html#toc

A lecture series from iisc more rigourous than felix

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLG9Skd-hzSi47tz_2QrJXige0F5lK-jvx

Answer (score -1):

http://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra

Here is one place to look

Comment: I'm not sure it provides H&K or Axler type coursework. It's way to basic.