# A good Linear Algebra Book for Someone with a rigorous background in it?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

**Tl;dr: Took a rigorous linear algebra 2 years ago, forgot most of the stuff now. Trying to resharpen my LA skills, so looking for a suitable LA book.**

2 Years ago, I took a very rigorous course in Linear Algebra and Abstract Algebra. We covered content such as Groups/homomorphisms, fields, rings, vector spaces, subspaces, linear transformations, rank/nullity, isomorphisms, matrix arithmetic, representation of linear maps by a matrix, computational algorithms, dot product, inner product spaces, determinants, spectral theory, and the Cayley Hamilton theory.

The course was very proof heavy, and I came out of the course with a solid understanding about the theory of linear algebra.

Fast forward 2 years later, I am trying to resharpen my linear algebra skills. I tried reading Strang's book but I got demotivated very quickly because I felt I was benefiting very little (as I remembered most of these stuff). However, at the same time, I have forgot lots of elementary bits and pieces in the middle so I can't say I remember everything!

So I guess what I am trying to ask is, is there a suitable book for my case which still starts with the basics but picks up the pace quickly, while still covering most of the elementary content?

Comment: And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403654/first-course-in-linear-algebra-book-suggestions?rq=1) are recommendations for many other books, too. There should be a suitable book among these books.

Comment: You might enjoy https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Problem-Dolciani-Mathematical-Expositions/dp/0883853221 by Halmos