# Search for a book for learning linear algebra, that gives lot of practical real world examples

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking for a book about linear algebra that explains everything, and shows real usage examples.
I mean that everything that written in the book is to solve real problems.

The examples can be in ANY field.

I saw here some recommendation for "Linear Algebra Done Right", but I don't see that it have examples.

**In other words:** I looking for a book that starts with a problem, and then teach the minimum required knowledge to solve the problem. And then shows the next problem that linear algebra solves.

I have read [Where to start learning Linear Algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/where-to-start-learning-linear-algebra)

(It is not opinion-based, an answer that mentions a book that have this  mind will be accepted)

Comment: Perhaps you should have started your search with... a search. The question I linked to specifically asks for books with applications, and the solutions give books with applications. I found it by searching for "linear algebra book recommendation applied applications"

Comment: physics does a lot of linear algebra, on the right graph constant acceleration is a straight line.

Comment: There are quite a few examples between economics, physics, geometry and more in $\textit{Linear Algebra}$ by Friedberg, Insel and Spence. The text is easy to follow and the material tends to be problem motivated although I am a little partial since I've really only seen a couple of linear algebra books.