# Need introduction to coordinate-free geometry

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request

Forgive my whiny tone -- I'm driving myself nuts.  These questions have
been driving me crazy and I'm losing objectivity.
I need a serious introduction to coordinate-free geometry.
Let me ask more than one question, not because I deserve multiple
answers but because I want to show exactly how I am confused and
thus get a better reference.  I'm after a reference, not answers.

I've searched Amazon's book section and it returns
books that are pretty obviously the stuff I studied back in
the 70s.  A google search for coordinate-free geometry tutorial
tends to return stuff that breezes past all the elementary stuff
and launches into differential geometry and so on.  I'm not ready
for that.

This was provoked by chapter 1 of Thorne and Blandford's book,
wherein the dot product is defined by

$$A \cdot B = \frac{1}{4}[(A+B)^2 - (A-B)^2]$$

Now, I can expand the rhs with the best of them.

$$A \cdot B = \frac{1}{2}[AB + BA]$$

But, what, precisely, is $AB$ in the above?
This is the kind of stuff I'm having trouble with.
Where can I get a real introduction to coord-free geometry that
will show me the algebra?

Allow me to drone on a bit.  Since I'm having trouble getting
graphics into my latex doc let me play a little fast and loose with
my example.  Consider the unit circle at the origin.  There's a *tangent*
line to that circle which is horizontal and runs through (0,1).
That's what I think of when I hear the word *tangent*.

Aside:  if I want to bend a sheet of aluminum I can take a
knife and a straightedge and *score* a line on the aluminum
and then bend it.  OTOH, as Lincoln said, ``four *score* and
seven years ago....''  Now, that's one word, *score*, used for
two completely separate things.

Back to my question:  If I try to read a book on manifolds
I tend to run into *tangent space*.  I can't get anyone to say
that *tangent space* doesn't mean  *tangent* at all.
If we "reserve" *tangent* to mean straight lines sitting
on curves, we don't "lose" anything by calling *tangent space*
something like *George space*.  That is, there's nothing *tangent*
about *tangent space*.  Right?

From the descriptions of *tangent space* it appears
that what it really boils down to is the set of all vectors using
the particular point as the origination point.  That is, that's
what I'm getting out of it.  Ah, here's another way to get
at my issue:  I'm worried that there's something I'm missing in
the descriptions of *tangent space* that somehow includes
some facet of *tangent*.

(Sigh.)  One more thing occurs to me:  Two points, $P$ and $Q$.
Deliberately ignoring/omitting the vectors between $P$ and $Q$,
assuming I'm right about what a *tangent space* is, that means
that a vector originating at $Q$ is not part of $P$'s *tangent space*.
Am I right?

(Deeper sigh.)  Also, I need a proper definition of this operator:  $\otimes$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by coordinate-free geometry? Linear algebra (this is where I learned about the dot product), differential geometry in euclidean spaces, abstract differential geometry (with abstract manifolds)?

Comment: I'm not sure that $AB$ and $BA$ have any meaning here. It might be $(A+B)^2$ and $(A-B)^2$ should be interpreted as $|A+B|^2$ and $|A-B|^2$, i.e. as their norms squared.

Comment: But in [geometric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra) they *do* have meaning.

Comment: Sorry but exactly what do you mean by "coordinate-free geometry"?  Things like Euclidean geometry before Cartesian coordinates were invented?  Or something more like finite geometry?

Comment: The symbol $\otimes$ usually stands for [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).

Comment: One thing is sure: "coordinate-free geometry" isn't an good descriptor. As said by md2perpe $AB$ has a meaning inside **"geometric algebra"** a rather recent (say 50 years) view on geometry. On the other hand, when you express your perplexity about what is really a "tangent space" which can indeed be rather far from our view of what a tangent is, you are in a totally different domain which is **"differential geometry"** (200 years) with, sooner or later, a very heavy use of "coordinates"... Besides, I don't understand what you mean by OTOH and the reference to Lincoln : could you explain me ?

Comment: OTOH == on the other hand

Comment: "four score..." is from the Gettysburg Address.  In that context score means 20.  four score and seven years == 87 years.  i should have avoided my parochial American assumption.  I often use this in conversation as an example of a word taking on disparate meanings.

Comment: Thank you for having taken time to answer me. I didn't know this meaning of the word "score".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the definitions by Thorne and Blandford is needlessly confusing (beside lacking rigor)

A **vector space** is a set (whose elements we call *vectors*) whose elements we can

- add together
- multiply by scalars (in physics usually real or complex  numbers).

We also require that these operations have "nice" properties, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) for more details.

An *example* of a vector space is the set of arrows with a common base point in the euclidean plane or 3D space, but there are many others.

A vector space can then be equiped with a dot product, which is a bilinear map $(A,B) \mapsto A\cdot B$ such that :

- $A\cdot B = B\cdot A$ for every two vectors $A$ and $B$ (we say that it is symmetric)
- $A\cdot A >0$ for any non-zero vector $A$

If we are given a dot product, we can *define* the length of a vector $A$ as $\|A\| =\sqrt{A\cdot A}$. Then, we can derive the so-called polarization identity :
$$A\cdot B = \frac{1}{4}\Big(\|A+B\|^2 - \|A-B\|^2\Big)$$

---

*Proof* :
Let $A,B$ be two elements of a vector space equipped with a dot product :
\begin{align}
\|A+B\|^2 &= (A+B)\cdot(A+B) \\
&= A \cdot(A+B) + B\cdot(A+B) \\
&= A\cdot A + A\cdot B + B\cdot A + B\cdot B \\
&= \|A\|^2 + 2A \cdot B + \|B\|^2
\end{align}
similarly we find :

\begin{align}
\|A-B\|^2 &= \|A\|^2 - 2A\cdot B + \|B\|^2
\end{align}

Therefore, we have :
\begin{align}
\frac14(\|A+B\|^2-\|A-B\|^2)&= \frac14\big(\|A\|^2 + 2A \cdot B + \|B\|^2-(\|A\|^2 + 2A \cdot B + \|B\|^2\big)\\
&= A\cdot B
\end{align}

---

To learn more about these points, take a book on linear algebra (some are recommended [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/where-to-start-learning-linear-algebra)).

---

$~$

---

$~$

---

About the definition of tangent space :  the use of the same word to describe different things need not be a problem, as context will usually make it clear which meaning is intended. When some of the different definition occur in the same context, it is best if they agree. Here, there is actually no problem, since there is *the tangent*, the *tangent space* and *tangent vectors*, so no confusion is possible.

Further more :

- If you consider a manifold immersed in euclidean space and a curve running in that manifold, than the tangent vector of the curve at a point will lie in the tangent space of the manifold at that point. In fact, the tangent space of the manifold $M$ at a point $p$ is exactly the set of tangent vectors to curves in $M$ running through $p$.
- A regular smooth curve $\gamma$ in euclidean affine space $A$ is an immersed submanifold. The tangent to $\gamma$ at a point $p$ is an affine subspace of $A$, whose direction is exactly the tangent space of $\gamma$ at $p$.

So actually, the different uses of *tangent* actually match pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Your product AB is called the geometric product, and it's what defines vectors in the first place. A dot product is the symmetric part of that basic product.