# Best Linear algebra self-study content as of Jan 2024

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

I am sure this question has been asked plenty of times, but I wanted to get the most up to date answer. I am a non-stem graduate looking to sharpen my math skills and want to start with Linear Algebra. What are the best ways of doing so on my own? I have read a decent amount of Paul's online math notes for Linear algebra but have found that rigor level to be low. Free resources are ideal but open to paid suggestions.

Comment: The course material for undergraduate linear algebra hasn't changed in the past 15 years, so any recommendations [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4335/81360) are fine for today. If what you're looking for is a comprehensive explanation that is more rigorous than Paul's notes, then you're unlikely to find it online.

Comment: A general advice : Never pay for references if there is a way to get them free. They are usually not better , often even worse than the free alternative. Which books are best is unfortunately a very subjective matter and what is helpful for person $X$ , might be not helpful for person $Y$. Just look at several sources and choose the one you are most content with.

Comment: Axler’s excellent textbook [Linear Algebra Done Right](https://linear.axler.net/) is free online.

Comment: MITOpenCourseWare has many excellent resources for linear algebra and other subjects at a rigorous level. It's where I learned it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend starting with Friedberg's Linear Algebra book or Lang's one. They're both great theoretical books. If you want some linear algebra on a higher dose then go for Michel Artins Algebra book.